# Setup an IPv6 6in4 Tunnel on macOS High Sierra 10.13

Tags: macos, network, ipv6

I'm trying to setup a 6in4 tunnel from my home with IPv4 only addressing to a Hurricane Electric tunnel for some IPv6 testing. I tried to create a new Interface:

```
System Preferences > Network > [+] in Interface List
```

But the UI only provides `6to4` which is the reverse (IPv4 services on an IPv6 only network).

Comment: tunnelbroker.net does not provide 6to4 tunnels, so that will never work. See their example configuration or https://gist.github.com/pklaus/960672 for a working setup.

Comment: @DavidAnderson derp. I'm confusing `6to4` with `6in4`

Comment: @MichaelHampton see my above comment, thanks for the script

Comment: @DavidAnderson maybe reverse isn't quite the right word, since one is a NAT and the other a tunnel. I'm on an IPv4 NAT behind a single semi-static IPv4, so I'm going to terminate the tunnel there. Sonic offers their own tunnel endpoint so I'm using that.